# Concrete Mix for making small objects

Tags: concrete, trim

I want to build desk objets out of concrete, such as the ones in the images below ( i don't own any of them, they have been taken from around the internet).

http://www.designboom.com/design/concrete-rollerball-pen-by-22-design-studio-at-designboom-shop/

[image]

and

http://fancycrave.com/concrete-desk-accessories/

[image]

The walls of these objects are not more than 4mm thick, what kind of mix would i need to make such objects so that they are durable ?

I have tried the normal sand, cement mixes but they don't seem to good enough at the thickness I am using. I have heard about GFRC and admixtures but i don't get to buy them where i live. So i am trying for a DIY solution from scratch.

Has anyone tried to build such objects ? If so what do you recommend. I am new to using  concrete, so please help me out...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The 'Hobby project' police will be coming for you..  try to incorporate a home improvement angle, such as concrete repair. Allowable topics: http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Two elements will help in casting small concrete parts..  A plasticizer, such as a latex admix and vibration of your mold, to cause bubbles to rise.

If you really can't get a latex admix, you might try latex paint, as a guess (keep the percentage low, <10% of your water)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will try mixing in some latex paint and see what the results are like. What does the plasticizer do in this mix?

Comment: Plasticiser improves the workability of the concrete, without adding excess water (which will reduce the ultimate strength of the conrete). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticizer#For_concrete